# Using a $apply inside a $watch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest

I have a non-isolate scope directive. I don't want to isolate it because it needs to be on elements with other directives. Yet I need to watch an item on scope.  So I tried this:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
     return scope.$apply(attrs.myAttribute);
}, function(val) {
     return val ? doSomething():doSomethingElse();
});
```

This does not work because angular throws a digest cycle already in progress error.  So my question is, how can I dynamically watch an item on scope with a non-isolate directive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call `$apply` inside of a `$watch` callback because `scope.$watch` internally calls `$apply` for you, which is why you are getting the "digest cycle already in progress error" error.

Instead you can simply do:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myAttribute, function(val){
  return val ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
};
```

The expression set to `myAttribute` will get evaluated against the scope of the element on which your directive sits since, like you mentioned, it is not isolated. And when the return value changes, the callback function will get invoked.

For example, if your HTML looked something like this

```
<div myNoNewScopeDirective myAttribute="doThis(value)"></div>
```

`doThis(value)` will get evaluated against the scope associated with the div element and its return value will be watched by your `myNoNewScopeDirective`. As a result, any change to such value will trigger the callback you provided and when `val` is truthy, `doSomething` will get invoked.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not believe this works. How can you call `scope.$watch(attrs` if there is nothing yet on scope? You can't just watch the attributes in this style, and the OP does not want an isolate scope - so a scope definition on the directive level will not suffice. Can you craft a small working demo of this? [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqej2b4j/) of how I interpret this answer. Can you make this functional?

Comment: @scniro   In my project the directive is inside the scope of a controller.  So I need the directive to watch something that was already defined on scope but do so dynamically.  for example if the controller had scope.foo defined on it, I needed my element to be like <element myDirective myAttr="foo">.  So whenever foo changed my directive could act accordingly.  I definitely get your answer as well, but I didn't want was in the attribute to be interpreted as a string.

Comment: but `myAttr="foo"` will not be watchable from inside the directive - it's just an attribute at that point and not bound in any way. How are you placing it on scope? @user3828000. `scope.$watch(attrs.myAttr, [...]` will always yield `undefined`,  
so in the example above, I'd suspect that `doSomethingElse()` will always fire

Comment: just curious is all, I'm not trying to bash this answer in any way

Comment: @scniro, here you go https://jsfiddle.net/rqej2b4j/1/. I think the confusion is that the property on the scope itself isn't changing, only the value that such property points to. In my experience, that's the more common use case - and not the that property that the attribute points to changing

Comment: @jbmilgrom hey good point there - I see you are modifying the scope value directly. Nice! I think the only way to watch it and update the element itself is in my first example where we actually watch `elem.attr('my-attribute')`, but, I don't think that's the main issue here

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your difficulties are watching the item if it is on scope already. Could you elaborate a bit on this? Regardless, here are two solutions which should cover almost all cases. To watch attribute changes, observe the following...

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return elem.attr('my-attribute');
}, function(n, o) {
    if(n) 
        console.log(n);
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qd4x6rxj/) - watch attribute demo

---

But, I suspect you are having difficulty getting the item on scope. If so, here is a way to assign it via `$observe` then watch it from there without an isolate...

```
attrs.$observe('myAttribute', function(value) {
    scope.myValue = value;
});

scope.$watch('myValue', function(n, o) {
    if(n) 
        console.log(n);
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/49vnqvu6/) - watch attribute demo via `$observe`